# Dumping Intermediate MR Job Data By Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a query with respect to how Pig behaves normally.

Suppose I am writing a Pig script as follows :

```
A = LOAD some Input;
B = FILTER A BY `some condition 1`;
C = FILTER A BY `some condition 2`;
D = GROUP B BY `some column1` ;
E = GROUP C BY `some column1` ;
store D;
store E;
```

Now Here, when Pig actually passes data, assume that Pig Creates 2 Jobs to Execute this script:

> Job 1 : Filters By Condition 1 and Condition 2
>
> Job 2 : Performs the Group By Operation.

So the output data of Job 1 is used By Job 2 as input; does Pig write the output data of Job 1 onto disk and then load that output data as the input data of Job 2, or does Pig directly pass the output of Job 1 to Job 2 (may be Storing the intermediate output in memory/RAM if it has enough) as a part of some optimization technique?

My question is when Pig fires multiple jobs, does each Job put its MR output to disk and then the next Job picks up the output as its input or does it somehow directly passes it to the next Job without writing it to the disk.

Any useful links supporting the conclusion will be of great help.

Thanks In Advance
Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pig internally executes jobs as DAG. Always in an MR job output of a job is stored to disk. So to answer your question precisely, it will pick output of job1 from disk.

Comment: Thanks Venkata, Can you please share some Documentation of its working as well.?